# SFML Network: сервер срабатывает только если число клиентов равно их максимальному количеству

Tags: c++, сеть, sfml

Если запустить сервер, то первое его обновление сработает при первом подключении, да и зациклится он только в том случае, если количество подключений будет равно числу максимальных подключений(maxClients)

Вот код, можете запустить у себя и проверить... (Здесь SFML и nlohmannJson)

```
class Server
{
public:
    bool active;
    int maxClients;
    Clock clock;
    nlohmann::json json;
    vector<TcpSocket*> socket;
    Packet packet;
    TcpListener listener;
    SocketSelector selector;
    Server(int maxClients)
    {
        active = true;
        this->maxClients = maxClients;
        
    }
    void update()
    {

        while (active)
        {
            
                //Если появился запрос на подключение - создать сокет и подключить его
                listener.listen(2000);
                TcpSocket* s = new TcpSocket; 
                if (socket.size() < maxClients)
                {
                    
                    listener.accept(*s);
                    socket.push_back(s);
                    selector.add(*s);
                    cout << "Connection successfully" << endl;
                    cout << socket.size() << "/" << maxClients<<endl;
                    cout << endl;

                    //передача параметров из listener в сокет
                }
                else
                {
                    s->disconnect();
                }
    

            json.clear();
            json["time"] = clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
            packet << json.dump();
            for (int l = 0; l < socket.size(); l++)
            {
        
                    socket[l]->send(packet);
                    
                    
            }
            //***//
            system("cls");
            cout << "**************************" << endl;
            cout << "Server status: ";
            switch (active)
            {
            case 0: cout << "false" << endl; break;
            case 1: cout << "true" << endl; break;
            }
            cout << "Connections: " << socket.size() << "/" << maxClients << endl;
            cout << "Life Time: " << round(json["time"].get<int>()) << endl;
            cout << "**************************" << endl;

            //***//

            packet.clear();
        }
    }
};
class Client
{
public:
    nlohmann::json json;
    TcpSocket socket;
    Packet packet;
    Client()
    {
        
        if (socket.connect(IpAddress::getLocalAddress(), 2000) == Socket::Done)
        {
            cout << "Connection successfully" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Error" << endl;
        }
    }
    void update()
    {
        
        while (true)
        {
            if (socket.receive(packet) != sf::Socket::Disconnected)
            {
                cout << "Listen..." << endl;
                socket.receive(packet);

                string data; packet >> data;
                json = nlohmann::json::parse(data);
                cout << json["time"].get<float>() << endl;
                packet.clear();
                sleep(seconds(1));
            }
            else
            {
        
                    system("cls");
                    cout << "Diconnected" << endl;
            
                
            } 
        }
        
        
        
    }
};
int main()
{
    char mode;
    cout << "Select mode: [s] - server; [c] - client" << endl;
    cin >> mode;
    if (mode == 's')
    {
        Server* server = new Server(20);
        while (true)
        {
            server->update();
        }
    }
    else if (mode == 'c')
    {
        Client* client = new Client();
        while (true)
        {
            client->update();
        }
    }
    else { cout << "Error: invalid mode" << endl; return -1; }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: вангую, что у вас бесконечный цикл пока количесвто подключений не достигнет лимита

Comment: да вроде нет...

Comment: Ну а в чем вопрос-то?